# Friendly URL with two parameter htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this code bellow that im trying to rewrite two paramters like that.

> Ex: www.mywebsite.com/chat.php?room=12&name=my_room_name

to rewrite it like that:

> www.mywebsite.com/chat/12/my_room_name

AND:

then if i have this last friendly url in php

if i write

```
  $room = $_GET['room'] ;
  $name = $_GET['name'] ;
  echo $room ."<br />"; //echo ->    12/my_room_name --> wrong should be 12
  echo $name ;  // echo nothing .  should be my_room_name
```

this is my htaccess code which i have

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}\s/+(?:chat\.php)?\?room=([^\s]+)&name=([^\s]+)? [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /chat/%1/%2? [R=301]
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^chat/(.*)$ chat.php?room=$1&name=$2 [QSA] 

  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /chat\.php\?r=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ chat/%1? [R=301,L,NE]
  RewriteRule ^chat/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ chat.php?r=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

I donbt know if there is something wrong , im new to htaccess .

How can be this solved thanks for your support ?

Comment: So, in other words, you want `/chat/12/my_room_name` to be rewritten to `chat.php?room=12&name=my_room_name`? Why are you using `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Za-z0-9]{3,}\s/+(?:chat\.php)?\?room=([^\s]+)&name=([^\s]+)? [NC]` then to rewrite to `/chat/%1/%2?`?

Comment: No i dont want to rewrite again , i just wanted to retrieve room and name but i couldnt .

Comment: What about `RewriteEngine on` ? Do you have that line in your htaccess file?

Comment: Yes i have that in the begining of file , sorry i will add that

Comment: @Ultimater Look my echo how they should be , i have eited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish by complicating your .htaccess file.
A simple .htaccess file that read only this would work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^chat/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /chat.php?room=$1&name=$2 [QSA,L]
```

If you need any further functionality, explain it here and I can edit my answer.

Comment: I have explained in my question how i want my url to be `www.mywebsite.com/chat/12/my_room_name` and then i will be able to retirieve `room` and `name` parameters from that rewriten url . Hope its clear. As you see i tried to echo them but they give me wrong result , look my edit how they echo

Comment: Your line `RewriteRule ^chat/(.*)$ chat.php?room=$1&name=$2 [QSA]` is wrong since it contains no `$2` to reference. I have given you a revised rule which should work.

Comment: i will just use your code ? or i have to replace your last line with which line in my code ? sorry as i said im new

Comment: My code should work on its own. Try running it first by replacing your whole .htaccess file. Once you see it works, try using just my RewriteRule in place of your `RewriteRule ^chat/(.*)$ chat.php?room=$1&name=$2 [QSA]` rule if you'd like to preserve whatever functionality you had working before.

Comment: Im very thankful for your very short code which worked for me:) , im so rubbish used many lines for nothing while you have just a single line :) . thanks so much :) . everything works good now . Thanks hero :)